# Asynchronous address resolution in winsock?

Tags: asynchronous, winsock, gethostbyname

Looking into asynchronous address resolution in winsock it seems that the only two options are either to use the blocking `gethostbyname` on a seperate thread, or use `WSAAsyncGetHostByName`. The latter is designed for some reason to work with window messages, instead of overlapped operations and completion ports/routines.

Is there any version of `gethostbyname` that works asynchronously with overlapped operations in a similiar manner to the rest of the winsock API?

Comment: The "some reason" it was designed that way is that Winsock was created in the Win16 world, where there were no threads or console-mode programs.  (There were DOS programs, but they had no access to Winsock, except by trickery.)  All Windows programs had a GUI, or at least a message loop, by which the OS told the program of things that have happened.  Notifying of finished name lookups through this mechanism makes sense, in that world.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there isn't at present, although [GetAddrInfoEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738518(VS.85).aspx) has placeholders for all the right things for async operation via all of the 'usual' routes (including IOCP) so I expect there will be eventually... Unfortunately, at this time, the docs say that all of these must be set to NULL and are marked as 'reserved'. :(

I'm just about to write one (have been for a while)... It's unfortunate that `WSAAsyncGetHostByName` doesn't even allow concurrent name resolution, so it's pretty useless as a base for what I want; but, then again, since it doesn't handle IPv6 that also makes it pretty useless to me. I expect I'll start from scratch; possibly using something like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adns/) (beerware) as a base.

Comment: Beware, the second library you link to is GPL'd.

Comment: Good spot Warren. I hadn't got as far as following it up yet. I only did the googling last night.

Comment: @LenHolgate You may want to update your answer. Starting with Windows 8, the Unicode version of `GetAddrInfoEx` does support async operations.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no overlapped version of gethostbyname().